# Deploying with zappa, Django project in subfolder

Tags: django, aws-lambda, zappa

I'm new to Docker, AWS Lambda and Zappa, but I'm trying to configure a project with very little success.

I connect to Docker (`docker-compose run web bash`), activate the environment, configure the AWS credentials and run `zappa init` and `zappa deploy`.  However, after deployment I get an error (executing `zappa tail`):

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'
```

I believe that that's because my dir structure is not the standard:

```
Dockerfile
zappa_settings.json
requirements.txt
project\
- manage.py
- root\
   - settings.py
   - wsgi.py
   - ...
```

So, my django project is inside the `project` folder, as I don't like having all the files thrown there and mixed with other configuration files.

My zappa config file looks like this:

```
{
    "dev": {
        "aws_region": "us-east-2",
        "django_settings": "project.root.settings",
        "profile_name": "default",
        "project_name": "task",
        "runtime": "python3.6",
        "s3_bucket": "bucket-name"
    }
}
```

And Dockerfile:

```
FROM lambci/lambda:build-python3.6

# Copy in your requirements file
ADD requirements.txt /requirements.txt

# Copy your application code to the container
RUN mkdir /code/
WORKDIR /code/
ADD . /code/

ENV PS1 'zappa@$(pwd | sed "s@^/var/task/\?@@")\$ '

ADD zappa_settings.json /var/task/zappa_settings.json

WORKDIR /var/task

RUN virtualenv /var/venv && \
    source /var/venv/bin/activate && \
    pip install -U pip zappa && \
    pip install -r /requirements.txt && \
    deactivate

CMD ["zappa"]
```

Can you tell me how to set it up correctly? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Latest error after moving to subfolder:

[image: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named root]

Comment: How about move `Dockerfile`,
`zappa_settings.json`,
`requirements.txt` files to same location with `manage.py` file and change zappa config to `"django_settings": "root.settings"`?

Comment: Thanks @Beomi.  Makes sense. However, I did that and now I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'root'`.  I'm adding a screeshot of the full error. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can keep your file structure with zappa and it will work perfectly fine.

Given the file structure

```
Dockerfile
zappa_settings.json
requirements.txt
project\
- manage.py
- root\
   - settings.py
   - wsgi.py
   - ...
```

You can simplify your `Dockerfile` to be

```
FROM lambci/lambda:build-python3.6

ADD . /var/task

RUN python -m venv /var/task/dockervenv && \
    source /var/task/dockervenv/bin/activate && \
    pip install -U pip zappa && \
    pip install -r /var/task/requirements.txt && \
    deactivate

WORKDIR /var/task

ENV PS1 'zappa@$(pwd | sed "s@^/var/task/\?@@")\$ '

CMD ["bash"]
```

And it seems from your update that you have gotten similar results because your Django application seems to reach the Django code.  Presumably you have also [edited your ALLOWED_HOSTS to accept incoming connections](https://edgarroman.github.io/zappa-django-guide/walk_core/#deploy-your-project-using-zappa)

Now the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'root'` is because your Django settings file is not expecting to exist within the subdirectory.  You must update the `settings.py` to update the variable

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.root.urls'
```

This should get you up and running.

**Side Effects of this docker approach**

As an aside, the way you are setting up your docker container has some implications on coding workflow.  Your docker image will contain a copy of your code at the time it was built.  So any edits on the code in a running docker container will be lost when the container ends unless exported somehow (e.g. git).  While this could be perfectly fine for stable code in a CI/CD pipeline, I would not recommend it for active development.

If you'd like to use it for active development, then when invoking docker, have your project directly mapped as a volume when the container is invoked.  For example:

`docker run -ti -v $(pwd):/var/task  --rm <name of your image>`

Comment: Thanks @Edgar. I believe I've tried that already and the error was `No module named 'project'`, but I'll try it again. As for the 'Side effect' note, what would you recommend? Just not working with Docker?  Because I'm on Windows I believe I have no choice, but I guess I could just move to Linux.

Comment: Diego, try it with the updated docker file i've pasted and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Just move, zappa_settings.json and the .json generated by zappa deploy to your subfolder.

Then update zappa_settings.json:
"django_settings": "project.root.settings" --> "django_settings": "root.settings"

cd into project folder and do a zappa update dev.

Not the best solution, but it worked for me